# Running a service on CentOS as a system user other than root

Tags: centos, systemd, root, services, non-root-user

I've created a system user `jackett` (`useradd -r jackett`) and I'm trying to run a systemd service under it on CentOS 7.

**Service File:**

```
[Unit]
Description=Jackett Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
user=jackett
group=jackett
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/Jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Service Status:**

```
[root@server Jackett]# systemctl status jackett
● jackett.service - Jackett Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jackett.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2019-02-23 23:42:23 +03; 11min ago
 Main PID: 24735 (mono)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jackett.service
           └─24735 /usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/Jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart

Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Loading Cardigann definition /opt/Jackett/Definitions/yourexotic.yml
Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Loading Cardigann definition /opt/Jackett/Definitions/zamundanet.yml
Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Loading Cardigann definition /opt/Jackett/Definitions/zelkaorg.yml
Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Loading Cardigann definition /opt/Jackett/Definitions/zooqle.yml
Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Loading Cardigann definition /opt/Jackett/Definitions/ztracker.yml
Feb 23 23:42:24 server mono[24735]: 02-23 23:42:24 Info Adding aggregate indexer
Feb 23 23:42:25 server mono[24735]: Hosting environment: Production
Feb 23 23:42:25 server mono[24735]: Content root path: /opt/Jackett/Content
Feb 23 23:42:25 server mono[24735]: Now listening on: http://[::]:9117
Feb 23 23:42:25 server mono[24735]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

`htop` **Shows Process Running Under Root**
[image]

Comment: @JeffSchaller `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Feb 23 22:25 /usr/bin/mono -> mono-sgen` this is what I get. Should I change the owner to `jackett`?

Comment: @JeffSchaller It shows the following `-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4591120 Jan 17 11:50 /usr/bin/mono-sgen`.

Comment: I haven't experimented to know for sure, but you could also try capital-U `User` instead of `user`... [reference](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=)

Comment: Capital-U! Thanks @JeffSchaller! Service is working now under `jackett` user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble is apparently that systemd is particular about case: `User` instead of `user`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Jackett Daemon
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=jackett
Group=jackett
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mono --debug /opt/Jackett/JackettConsole.exe --NoRestart

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Reference:

- [systemd.exec — Execution environment configuration -- User and Group](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#User=)